# Spark Execution for twitter Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, typesafe-config

Hi I'm new to spark and scala . I'm trying to stream some tweets through spark streaming with the following code:

```
object TwitterStreaming {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("WrongUsage:   PropertiesFile, [<filters>]")
      System.exit(-1)
    }

    StreamingExamples.setStreaningLogLevels()
    val myConfigFile = args(0)
    val batchInterval_s = 1
    val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(myConfigFile))
    val appConf = ConfigFactory.load(fileConfig)  
    // Set the system properties so that Twitter4j library used by twitter stream
    // can use them to generate OAuth credentials

    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", appConf.getString("consumerKey"))
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", appConf.getString("consumerSecret"))
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", appConf.getString("accessToken"))
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", appConf.getString("accessTokenSecret"))

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterStreaming").setMaster(appConf.getString("SPARK_MASTER"))//local[2]

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchInterval_s)) // creating spark streaming context
    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
    val tweet_data = stream.map(status => TweetData(status.getId, "@" + status.getUser.getScreenName, status.getText.trim()))
    tweet_data.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      println(s"A sample of tweets I gathered over ${batchInterval_s}s: ${rdd.take(10).mkString(" ")} (total tweets fetched: ${rdd.count()})")
    })
  }

}

case class TweetData(id: BigInt, author: String, tweetText: String)
```

My Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType:/WorkSpace/InputFiles/application.conf: 5: Cannot concatenate object or list with a non-object-or-list, ConfigString("local") and SimpleConfigList([2]) are not compatible
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigConcatenation.join(ConfigConcatenation.java:116)
```

can any one check the the code and tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @gsamaras I want to map to TweetData class... Is any thing wrong in doing that?

Comment: as per me the error is on passing "local[2]" as SPARK_MASTER.If that is the case how to SET SPARK_MASTER

Comment: please show the relevant line in your config file (the one with SPARK_MASTER) - it seems to violate the format expected by `typesafe.config`. You can narrow down the question to contain only the contents of the file and the two lines of code loading the config file - that's where the exception is, no need for all the rest...

Comment: @TzachZohar two-lines of code `val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(myConfigFile))
    val appConf = ConfigFactory.load(fileConfig)`  and file contains `consumerKey=xxx
consumerSecret=xxx
accessToken=xxx
accessTokenSecret=xxx
SPARK_MASTER="local[2]"`

Comment: better to update the question instead of commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your config file contains:

```
SPARK_MASTER=local[2]
```

Change it to:

```
SPARK_MASTER="local[2]"
```

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: @Tzach Zohar  After changing I'm getting  Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address

Comment: This sounds like a whole other question to me, so I can't answer it here. Try searching SO / Google, this is standard Spark stuff... In the meantime it would be helpful for future readers if you edit the question to contain all of the the relevant information and _only_ it - meaning the config file entry and the code that loads it.

Comment: BTW - if "Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address" appears as a _warning_ and not an _error_ - you can ignore it, it shouldn't interfere with execution.

Comment: @TzachZohar Thanks ..It is working ...Thanks all for the support